# LINQ Query Returns List of Lists

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a query:

```
from m in dc.ReportingMonths
where m.Month.Value == month
select (from k in m.KPI_Actives
        where k.DateActive.Year == year
        select (from r in dc.ReportingViews
                where r.KPIID == k.KPIID select r)
       );
```

Obviously, because it is nested LINQ queries - each returning an IQueryable I get a set of IQueryables as a result.

How do I write a similar query that instead just returns a single flat list of ReportingViews (as the last query returns) without using foreach loops to create a new list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
from m in dc.ReportingMonths where m.Month.Value == month
from k in m.KPI_Actives
where k.DateActive.Year == year
from r in dc.ReportingViews
where r.KPIID == k.KPIID
select r;
```

?

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realise I could do that without the select statements at every point.